# ssh2_auth_password always returns true even with wrong password

Tags: php, ssh

I am trying to connect to a server using PHP SSH2 functions.

This is the code I am testing:

```
if(!($con = ssh2_connect("123.123.123.123", 22))){
    echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n";
} else {
    if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "test", "test")) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
    } else {
        echo "connected";
        ssh2_exec($con, 'exit');
        unset($con);
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter what I put as user and password, the `ssh2_auth_password()` always returns true.

The following `ssh2_exec` just hangs the PHP script until I close it.

Why could this be happening?

---

Output of `ssh` for the same credentials:

```
vm@vm ~/ $ ssh -vvvv test@123.123.123.123
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 123.123.123.123 [123.123.123.123] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/vm/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vm/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vm/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vm/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vm/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vm/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.52
debug1: no match: dropbear_0.52
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "123.123.123.123" from file "/home/vm/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/vm/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,3des-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib,zlib@openssh.com,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib,zlib@openssh.com,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 121/256
debug2: bits set: 504/1024
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA xx:f3:xx:97:xx:b4:xx:2b:xx:e7:xx:87:xx:44:xx:b3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "123.123.123.123" from file "/home/vm/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/vm/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '123.123.123.123' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/vm/.ssh/known_hosts:9
debug2: bits set: 513/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/vm/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/vm/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/vm/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vm/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/vm/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vm/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/vm/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vm/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/vm/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
test@123.123.123.123's password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 64 (len 59 padlen 5 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 123.123.123.123 ([123.123.123.123]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_COOKIE
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env DEFAULTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env MANDATORY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env MDM_XSERVER_LOCATION
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env MDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env MDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 24576 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
login failed: please enter correct username and password
Login:
```

Comment: 1) Can you show us a log file from a regular SSH client with the same wrong password? 2) What does `ssh2_exec` do?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I edited the question with the answers. BTW same thing seems to happen with phpseclib, and in two servers from different hosting.

Comment: A log file please or a debug output (`ssh -vvvv`).

Comment: A [phpseclib log](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html#net_ssh_debug) would be helpful too.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Added -vvvv log, can't get the phpseclib working atm, will try again when I get to my pc at home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the log, even the `ssh` believes that the password authentication succeeded:

> debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).

I believe what happens is that:

- the client (`ssh` or `ssh2_auth_password`) sends the password
- the server always accepts the password (in the terms of the SSH protocol)
- but when the password is actually wrong, the server prints error

  > login failed: please enter correct username and password

  and prompts for a password (`Login:`) on the *terminal*. It's the same kind of message and prompt as for example a command prompt. The SSH client is not aware that it's about password. It rightfully believes that the authentication succeeded and a normal shell session is going on.

In other words, the `ssh2_auth_password` behaves correctly. It's the server that is implemented incorrectly.